# How can I display a consolidated version of my SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider this simplified scenario for an SQL Server database. This is not exactly the way my tables are built, but the example is enough for what I need to know.

I have a product table with a primary key, let's say, `IdProduct`, and some other columns, like the product name and description.

Then I have something like a total sales per month table (`SalesPerMonth`). This second table holds some fields like:

```
IdMonthlySale (key)
IdProduct (foreign key to the main table)
TotalSales (money)
Monthy (int or smallint)
Year (int or smallint)
```

The second table will hold the detailed info. We can track the sales of a certain product by doing a `SELECT * FROM SalesPerMonth WHERE ProductId = xx`

But let's say I want to display this data as if it wasn't normalized. I want a flat Product X Month/Year table that shows the last 8 months. Something more or less like this:

```
  Prod     *  Jan  *  Feb  *  Mar  *  Apr  *  May  *  Jun  *  Jul  *  Aug  *
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Prod 1     * 500.00* 480.00* 470.00* 510.00* 555.00* 530.00* 440.00* 490.00*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Prod 2     * 650.00* 680.00* 670.00* 710.00* 755.00* 630.00* 740.00* 820.00*
```

Well. I hope you get the idea. I need to flatten the resulting table and I need to output it that way to my users. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with SQL Server 2005 you can use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) to do this

In SQL 2000 you can use a series of  CASE statement e.g.

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 1 THEN Value ELSE 0 END ) as Jan,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 2 THEN Value ELSE 0 END ) as Feb,
```

If you don't care about the field names you can use offset off an input.

```
DECLARE @CurrentMonth = @Input;
DECLARE @CurrentMonth1 = @Input -1;
DECLARE @CurrentMonth2 = @Input -2;
```

and then do your SUM/CASE off that

```
   e.g.  
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = @CurrentMonth  THEN Value ELSE 0 END ) as Month0,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = @CurrentMonth1 THEN Value ELSE 0 END ) as Month1,
```

Then in your display (report/application) you resolve what to put as column headings

Comment: Yes, I do have it... I will have a look.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to go with your hint. I will possibly get back here and ask more stuff, buth this is very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the help. In the end, after some research, I found this great article (http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) about dynamic SQL (because I needed a dynamic SQL in order to find the columns I needed in my Pivot) and this fantastic Stored Procedure (http://www.sommarskog.se/pivot_sp.sp) that will dynamically find the fields you need in your query and place them dynamically as columns.